# How to retrieve [object Text] via XPath?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am working on selenium and trying to access text from a node but I'm not sure how to fetch and assert a text that has keyword approved.

This is the node -

```
<div class="Notification-body">
    <div class="">
        <div class="type--primary u-textBreak">
            <span class="u-inline">
                <span class="type--title">User Name</span> approved "Page_For_Submission"
            </span>
        </div>
        <span class="u-displayBlock type--note">4 hours ago</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initially I tried this XPath but it is giving no result -

```
(//span[contains(@class,'title')]/following-sibling::text()[contains(text(),'approved')])[1]
```

means this is not a simple text node.

Later I used following XPaths and able to locate position of the element

```
(//html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/div/div/div/div/span/text())[2]
```

```
//span[contains(@class,'title')]/following-sibling::text()
```

```
(//span[contains(@class,'title')]/following-sibling::text()[contains(.,'approved')])[1]
```

But by using these XPaths in selenium

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("txt_approvedNotification"))).getText());
```

Getting following error while executing

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "(XPath of Element)[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: '*****', ip: '*****', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.90,
```

Just want to know if its XPath issue or seleniumdriver limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium cannot wrap a single particular text node into WebElement. So as the soultion you can prepare and execute JavaScript code that would find the textnode you require, wrap it into a tag and add to the DOM with some unique ID. Then you'll be able to ontain that element with Selenium (`findElement(By.id())`).

Find some details here https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/33097/27679

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer but there is a much simpler alternative. Just grab the parent element and assert that "approved" is in the contained text. You didn't put a code tag, so the sample code below is in C# and uses NUnit for the assert. You might have to adjust the locator if it doesn't uniquely find the element but the code below demonstrates the core concept of asserting that a specific string is inside of a particular element.

```
StringAssert.Contains("approved", driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.u-inline")).Text, "Verify that X was 'approved'.");
```